# NodeJS callbacks and forloops

Tags: node.js

So I'm working on a text-game-thingy when I realize that I'm getting an error every once-in-a-while (~1/100 refreshes) when leaving the game. I have a basic object holding properties containing a player object. I also have a 'textCooldown' property in my player object (to stop you from spamming), and a 'setInterval' function to reduce this property's value every x seconds that looks, for all intensive purposes, like this:

```
setInterval(function() { 
  for(var p in PLAYER_LIST) {
    var player = PLAYER_LIST[p];
    player.textCooldown -= 0.1;
  }
}, 100);
```

I also have a function that gets called whenever the client disconnects, which deletes that property inside PLAYER_LIST. The problem is, every once in a while when a client disconnects the server is still calling the 'for' loop (which tells me NodeJS is multithreaded in at least some aspects) and tries to change the property 'textCooldown' of an undefined object.

How can I fix this problem without putting `if(typeof player != 'undefined'` everywhere? Is there any way I can implement callbacks into this seemingly synchronous task?

Comment: the setInterval function returns an `id`, that `id` stands as a reference to that particular call, you have use `clearInterval(id)`, to kill that executing interval

Comment: @0.sh I think you misunderstood my problem. I need to be constantly lowering each player's textcooldown property. What's happening is when a player disconnects while the for-loop is running, the for-loop doesn't know that and still tries to change the no longer existing object 'p'.